# How can I do Bubbles in OpenGL iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I must  develop some bubbles which will contain some part of main background image.
1 I never use OpenGL ES2.
  Do you know some book or books which help me understand openGl?

2.How can I do screenshot some background image in OpenGl?

3.How can I set some image in inside of the sphere?

Answer (score 1):

1) Try some example to begin with like [GLPaint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html)

2) You can make an UIView screenshot:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

3) You need to generate and [load a texture from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362868/convert-an-uiimage-in-a-texture). Then create correct [vertex coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500908/how-to-load-a-texture-onto-a-circle-with-opengl-es) and draw them. Or you can create a [fragment shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876640/how-to-use-fragment-shader-to-draw-sphere-ilusion-in-opengl-es) that does all of that and draw only a square.